# SQL - select IDs that have been seen in table w/ timestamp <= 1+ year

Tags: sql

I have a table with user IDs, timestamps, and sales info. The same user IDs appear multiple times in the data (every time they purchase). I only want to select the user IDs that have shown up in the table for at least a year (so, for the sake of simplicity I'll do a timestamp less than "12-31-2016"). How can I write this with SQL?

Comment: This post shows zero research or effort on your part. You already basically said the query.  "Select user IDs... From the table.... With a timestamp less than 2016-12-31".

Comment: I'm having trouble because I want to select the userID if in that row it has a timestamp greater than that, but in another row that same userID has a timestamp less than that

Comment: **[edit]** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). Also: which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Select Distinct userID
FROM Table
WHERE DATEDIFF(yy,cast(Timestamp as date),getdate())>=1
```

Updated based on your comment:

```
Select Distinct userID
FROM Table
WHERE CAST(Timestamp as date)>'20161231'
```

Comment: If you want to show the users that stay for at least one year